# emberJS 2 : nested relationships resources for actions (update & delete)

Tags: javascript, api, ember.js, ember-data, relationships

I'm asking you about relationships with Ember Data.

I have a User that belongs to an account and a cloud. Datas are well associated with URLs.

The API is done like this :

> *GET users/:id* -> send the user
>
> *GET users/:id/account* -> send the account status infos
>
> *GET users/:id/cloud* -> send the cloud status infos

What I need :

> I need to be able to update the account and cloud using the user id
>   info. The API expects this :
>
> *PATCH users/:id* -> update the user
>
> *PATCH users/:id/account* -> update the account associated to the userId. The userId is enough in the API side, but we can if necessary
>   send the account id like this -> users/:id/account/:idaccount

The same URLs with the DELETE http method to DELETE accounts.

When I trigger a "model.get('account').get('content').save() it sends

> accounts/:idaccount

But our API doesn't work like this...

Do you have an idea about how I could manage it ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ember-Data's JSONAPIAdapter or any other RESTAdapter, then you want to override [`urlForUpdateRecord`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_urlForUpdateRecord). [`Snapshot.prototype.belongsTo`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Snapshot.html#method_belongsTo) will also be useful. I'd guess something like

```
// app/adapters/account.js:
urlForUpdateRecord(id, modelName, snapshot) {
  const userId = snapshot.belongsTo('user', { id: true });
  return `/users/${userId}/account`;
}
```

Comment: Yes I use JSONAPIAdapter. I use this override function in my account adapter, right ?

Comment: Yes, in the `adapter:account`.